# Form validation With File Upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am having a form with a file upload.

i need to validate the form

here's my validation code

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('career_experience','Experience','trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('career_salary','Salary','trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('career_resume','Resume','callback_check_file');

function check_file($str)
{
   if($str=="")
        {
             $this->form_validation->set_message('check_file', 'Please Upload A Resume');
             return false;
        }
        else if($str!="")
        {
             $ext = array();
             $ext = explode(".",$str);
             $allowed_ext = array("doc","pdf","pdf","docx","txt");
             if(isset($ext[1]) && $ext[1]!="")
                {
                    if (in_array($ext[1], $allowed_ext)) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_file', 'The File Is Not Supported');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        }

}
```

Now the issue is that the validation message for career_resume always gives me

```
"Please upload a resume";
```

so it means even if i am selecting a file, its stating $str as empty string or "" string;

Why is that so??

Doesn't it take `$str = $_FILES['name'];`

Now career resume is the input="file"

here's the form

```
<form name="career_form" id="career_form" method="post"
            enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('pages/send_career_mail');?>">
<input name="career_experience" type="text"/>
<input name="career_salary" type="text"/>
<input name="career_resume" type="file"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Check again please, actualy i mistok file as text in <input type="text" name="career_resume"/>

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you set the `$str` parameter?

Comment: its codeigniter callback function for form validation method

Comment: Aah. Unfortunately i'm not well-known with codeigniter, but maybe it doen't fill the `$str` parameter with the file? What do you see if you use `print_r($_FILES)`? It is possible to use `$_FILES` instead of the `$str` parameter, isn't that an option?

Comment: @Saswat Doesn't it take $str = $_FILES['name']; - no

You have to validate it using $_FILES.

Comment: Also, try the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357239/2526639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In View:**

```
<input name="career_resume" type="file"/>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$file_name = $_FILES['career_resume']['name'];
```

**Correction:**

Added `['career_resume']`

**Explanation:**

When you print your **`$_FILES`** array you get the the details of the in a key which is actually the `name` of the input file tag.

```
print_r($_FILES);

// will give you below array

Array
(
    [career_resume] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc.csv
        [type] => text/csv
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkmmKZU
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 5466
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<input name="career_resume" type="text"/>
```

Should be

```
<input name="career_resume" type="file"/>
```