# Codeigniter File Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know with my code how am I able to make my file upload required. Because codeigniter form validation set rules is for post only.

I am unsure on how to make the file upload a requirement on form submit so it checks if file is required. And lets me submit form if file is upload or something along those lines

The callback works fine but required function cannot get to work with file upload.

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Store_add extends MX_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->session->userdata('isLogged')) {
        redirect('admin');
    }

    $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_store_add');
    $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_store_get');

    $this->lang->load('admin/setting/store_add', $this->settings->get('config_admin_language'));
}

public function index() {
    // Title Language
    $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_image', 'Store Image', 'callback_do_upload_image');

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) { // "$this is for HMVC MY_Form_validation"

        return $this->load->view('setting/store_add.tpl');

    } else {

        $store_id = $this->model_store_add->add_store();

        $this->do_upload_image($store_id);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('text_success'));

        redirect('admin/setting/store');

    }

}

public function do_upload_image($store_id) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './image/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_ext_allowed');
    $config['max_size'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_max_size');
    $config['overwrite'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_overwrite');
    $config['max_width'] = '*';
    $config['max_height'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('config_image')) {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload_image',  $this->upload->display_errors('<b>config_image</b>' .' '));

        return false;

    } else {

        if ($store_id) {

            $this->model_store_add->add_config_image($store_id, $this->upload->data());

        } 


    }
}   
}
```

Sample View form

```
<div class="panel-body">
<?php $data = array('id' => 'form-store-add', 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal' );?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/setting/store/add', $data);?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
<?php echo $this->load->view('setting/store_flashdata.tpl');?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-image"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="hidden" name="config_image" value="<?php echo set_value('config_image', '');?>">
<input type="file" name="config_image" size="20"/>
</div>
</div>

<?php echo form_close();?>

</div>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289225/codeigniter-file-upload-required-validation

Comment: tried it does not work.

Comment: Do you have code for your form? And just to clarify, checking the `POST` variables is not an option?

Comment: I added of sample view to the original post

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING NOW:** I did more research on http://php.net/ I have fixed form validation for file upload made sure it is required I added **is_file_upload** and also added set form validation message with a return of false

```
public function do_upload_image($store_id) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './image/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_ext_allowed');
    $config['max_size'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_max_size');
    $config['overwrite'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_overwrite');
    $config['max_width'] = '*';
    $config['max_height'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['config_image']['tmp_name'])) {

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('config_image')) {

                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload_image',  $this->upload->display_errors('<b>config_image</b>' .' '));

                return false;

            } else {

                if ($store_id) {

                    $this->model_store_add->add_config_image($store_id, $this->upload->data());

                }
            }

        } else {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload_image',  'Image Required');
            return false;

        }
}
```

Comment: Please, user markdown for code snippets http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting