# CodeIgnter3 Upload Image/pdf form validtion

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, image-uploading

I have two image upload/pdf fields which are validated with a callback function as follow:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Upload Image', 'callback_upload_image');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cv', 'Upload CV', 'callback_upload_cv');
```

I have two separate function upload_image and upload_cv but when I submit the form, it always calls the first (image_upload) function. So, the second callback function is not working.

Any ideas please?

Comment: If you have two fields on the page, it will perform the two callbacks. That's the idea.

What's the error you get? 'cause to me, it looks like there's a trouble on your callback. Keep in mind that those callback should return true or false in order to work properly with form validation.

Comment: hi check my answer on this post hope this will work for you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289225/codeigniter-file-upload-required-validation/12292861#12292861

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem.
I have restrict my form validation call as:

```
if($_FILES['source']['name'] != ''){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('source', 'Upload Image',  'callback_upload_image');
}
if($_FILES['cv']['name'] != ''){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cv', 'Upload CV', 'callback_upload_cv');  
}
```

and in upload_cv function instead of load upload library I used:
    $this->upload->initialize($config); //to reinitialize the config variable values.
Now, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem.
You can Add Jquery validation on it in your HTML tag give id or class and in the script, you have validated using their excitation.