# File not being stored with form_upload with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am attempting to create a gallery with CodeIgniter. However, when I attempt to process the form I receive the validation error "The Featured Image field is required" even though I selected a file. See View code below:

```
<section class="content">
    <?php 
        $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        if (isset($message)) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">' . $message . '</div>';
            $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
        }
    ?>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">
                            <?php echo empty($gallery->id) ? 'Add A New Gallery' : 'Edit Gallery' . $gallery->name; ?>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $gallery->name), 'class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Full Name" autocomplete="off"'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body pad">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Description</label>
                                <?php echo form_textarea('description', set_value('description', $gallery->description), 'class="form-control textarea" placeholder="Enter description"'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">
                        Featured Image
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <?php echo form_upload('thumbnail', set_value('thumbnail', $gallery->thumbnail), 'id="imgInp"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Add Gallery', 'class="btn btn-block btn-primary"'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</section>
```

I've tried recreating the form multiple times but I keep getting the same error. I tried form_open and got the same result. Any suggestions?  The controller is below:

```
 public function edit($id = null){
        // Fetch a user or set a new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['page_title'] = 'Edit Gallery';
            $this->data['user'] = $this->gallery_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['gallery']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'Gallery could not be found';
        }else{
            $this->data['page_title'] = 'Add New Gallery';
            $this->data['gallery'] = $this->gallery_m->get_new();
        }

        // Set up the form
        $rules = $this->gallery_m->rules_admin;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('thumbnail')){
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }else{
                //file is uploaded successfully
                //now get the file uploaded data 
                $imagedata = $this->upload->data();

                //get the uploaded file name
                $data['pic_file'] = $imagedata['file_name'];

                //store pic data to the db
                $this->pic_model->store_pic_data($data);

                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', 'Gallery Added Successfully' );
            }
        }

        // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/gallery/edit';
        $this->load->view( 'admin/body', $this->data );
    }
```

Below is the Galler Model which include the rules:

```
class Gallery_M extends MY_Model{
    protected $_table_name = 'gallery';
    protected $_order_by = 'datesubmitted';

    public $rules_admin = array(
        'name' => array(
            'field' => 'name', 
            'label' => 'Name', 
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        ), 
        'description' => array(
            'field' => 'description', 
            'label' => 'Description', 
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        ),
        'thumbnail' => array(
            'field' => 'thumbnail', 
            'label' => 'Featured Image', 
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        )
    );


    public function get_new(){
        $gallery = new stdClass();
        $gallery->name ='';
        $gallery->description = '';
        $gallery->views = '';
        $gallery->thumbnail = '';
        $gallery->datesubmitted = date('Y-m-d');
        return $gallery;
    }

    public function set_submitted(){
        $this->db->where('datesubmitted <=', date('Y-m-d'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in the view. Add the code for the controller to your question.

Comment: In the rendered HTML for the form, does the `<form>` tag have the proper enctype set to provide for multipart file uploads? `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name=... action=... method=...>`

Comment: @ivanivan the render is as follow: <form action="http://pgjamaica.lh/admin/gallery/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: @DFriend I added the controller function

Comment: Since it's the controller who throws the exception, we need to see that

Comment: the first obvious thing is that your form points to nowhere: `<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>` should actually be `<?php echo form_open_multipart('controller/method'); ?>`

Comment: @JavierLarroulet my form process fine when I am not validating the file input. But when I do I keep receiving an error that's the field is empty. That is the problem I am trying to address

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out... the message you're getting appears to be coming from CI's form_validation for which you're setting rules here `$rules = $this->gallery_m->rules_admin;` within those (which is code that's not available in your question right now) there should be a required field named "Featured image" that's failing to validate. Could you share that piece of code? looks like the problem points to that

Comment: FYI required and validation rules only work with POST variables and not file variables ;)

Comment: Now add the rules code

Comment: Similar here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289225/codeigniter-file-upload-required-validation

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I include the model where the rules where defined

Comment: @RamonHenry I just added an answer for you.. let me know if you can make it work.

Comment: Got it work thank you all for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `files` sent over a multipart form are not accesible through `$this->input->post()` and thus not possible to validate using `form_validation` because `form_validation` doesn't "see" them.

If you need to validate that the file was uploaded correctly, you may use:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
  // handle the error. You may get CI's error messages with
  // $this->upload->display_errors();
  // which covers both the existance or lack thereof of an uploaded file, as well as compliance with the upload constraints set by you when initializing the library
}
```

In the above example, `userfile`is the name of the file input on my form. In your case it should be `thumbnail`.

The regular `form_validation` still applies to the other fields of your form. You can group the both in a single array doing something like:

```
$data = array(
    'upload_data'   => $this->upload->data(),
    'form_data'     => $this->input->post(),
);
```

Give it a try and let me know if it works

Comment: By removing the thumbnail rule it processed the form thanks for the help